# Are there any common ID's on ListEmail class and EmailStatus class?

Tags: email

Are there any common ID's on ListEmail and EmailStatus classes?

My task is to get the emailstatuses of list emails sent through a campaign. I know that ListEmail class can get the CampaignID. But now I need to get the Email Statuses of those emails. Is that possible? I would be able to do it by the ownerid of the listemail or by the campaignid.  Are there any common fields between listemail and emailstatus?

Comment: Need to connect these:
1. campaign camp = [select id from campaign where id = '7013l000000yq77AAA'];
2. list<listemail> le = [select id, createddate, fromaddress, totalsent, ownerid from listemail where campaignid = :campid];

with this: List<Contact> contList = [Select id, name, CreatedDate, lastModifiedDate, email,
                         (SELECT  id, taskId, createdDate, firstOpenDate, lastOpenDate, timesOpened, emailTemplateName, task.subject, task.TaskSubtype FROM EmailStatuses where createddate = today and task.tasksubtype = 'ListEmail' )   from Contact where email != null ];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this: when a List Email is sent from a campaign, that list email can be queried by campaignid = the campaign's id.  Also, when a list email is sent out, task records (one for each contact who was sent the email) is simultaneously created, and the whatid of that task = the id of the ListEmail.